# Boto DynamoDB2 Iterate on query resultset does not work

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am using boto v2.16 and DynamodDB2 API. Following the tutorial in the official documentation of boto, dynamodb2 when I do:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
photos = Table('photos') # photos is a table
def get_image_urls():
    # photo_id is hashkey and type is rangekey
    allphotos = photos.query(photo_id__gte = 0, type__eq = 'Homedesign')

    # This prints <boto.dynamodb2.results.ResultSet object at 0x02981CF0>
    print allphotos

    #When I try to iterate the resultset, I get an error        
    for eachphoto in allphotos:
        print eachphoto['photo']
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to iterate over the resultset allphotos

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\coding\FL\ongoing jobs\django - FB\facebook-app-rating\rating\insert_data.py", line 75, in <module>
    get_image_urls()
  File "E:\coding\FL\ongoing jobs\django - FB\facebook-app-rating\rating\insert_data.py", line 59, in get_image_urls
    for eachphoto in allphotos:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\results.py", line 59, in next
    self.fetch_more()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\results.py", line 114, in fetch_more
    results = self.the_callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\table.py", line 868, in _query
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\layer1.py", line 975, in query
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\layer1.py", line 1487, in make_request
    retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 898, in _mexe
    status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\layer1.py", line 1527, in _retry_handler
    response.status, response.reason, data)
boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'Query key condition not supported', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}
[Finished in 17.1s with exit code 1]
```

Don't know what's going on! Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was actually some silly mistake. The filter gte (greater than equal) was not allowed on hashkey. There is only one filter allowed on hashkey which is eq (equal). So as I removed that, and it worked fine. Actually I deleted the table photos, recreated it by swapping the hashkey and the rangekey and updated the query code as:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
photos = Table('photos') # photos is a table
def get_image_urls():
    # photo_id is rangekey and type is hashkey
    allphotos = photos.query(type__eq = 'Homedesign', photo_id__gte = 1)

    print allphotos

    for eachphoto in allphotos:
        print eachphoto['photo']
```

This works well!